# Expectation brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

I am having trouble getting from the last step to the answer, this is highlighted in red.

[image: question]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the result of the exponential expectation below

$$E[e^{B_t}]=e^{\frac t2}$$

to get

$$E[e^{{B_1}+2}]=e^{\frac 52}$$

Comment: Is this because B_t ~N(0,t) and E(e^x) = e^(mean + 0.5sigma^2) 
and since mean=0 and sigma 1, we get the answer?

Comment: That is correct,